How to search for a string in post_content along with other arguments
I am looking for WordPress pages with a shortcode [aa_sliced_invoice_schedule] with a post_status of publish, draft or trash.  As per the WordPress Development Handbook, I am not using direct database calls. The following code filters on post_type, and post_status but not on post_content:
$arguments = array(
            "numberposts"   => -1,
            "post_type"     => 'page',
            "post_content"  => '%aa_sliced_invoice_schedule%',
            "post_status"   => array ('publish', 'draft', 'trash' ),
            "orderby"       => "post_title",
            "order"         => "ASC"
         );
$find_my_pages = get_posts($arguments);

Afterwards I have to add the following code to further filter on post_content:
if( count( $find_my_pages ) > 0 ) {
            foreach( $find_my_pages as $my_pages ) {
                $post_id      = esc_attr( $my_pages->ID );
                $post_name    = esc_attr( $my_pages->post_name );
                $post_content = esc_attr( $my_pages->post_content );

                if (str_contains( $post_content, '[aa_sliced_invoice_schedule]' )) {
                    $found_post_name = $post_name;
                    $found_post_id   = $post_id;
                }
            } 
        }

How can I do it in the arguments array and not have to add the second block of code?
I was expecting the argument array item: "post_content"  => '%aa_sliced_invoice_schedule%'  to further filter pages with this shortcode.

post_content, although a property on WP_Post, is not a search option directly. Instead use s without the % and it will search that column and a couple of others. If you want to limit it to only that column you can also set search_columns
